# How to understand a request coming from Angular and Redirect it in Java

Tags: java, angularjs, servlets, redirect

I want to redirect a user to login page if another user logged in with the same username.

I can understand whether a request is ajax with

```
boolean isAjax = "XMLHttpRequest".equals(httpRequest.getHeader("X-Requested-With"));
```

If request is ajax, I send an error to client and redirect with `location.href = 'to the login page'`.
If it is not, I redirect it on server side with `httpResponse.redirect("to the login page")`.

But some request are sent with $http of angularJS. I cannot understand if it is sent this way and I cannot redirect to login page.

How can I do this properly?

**NOTE:** I should do this on server side or on client side in a global way, because there are many places sending requests with $http of angular.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **responseInterceptor** in AngularJS through a $httpProvider service and identify the response before serving ahead.

Below is a sample code which uses a logic to understand if the response was ok. If error occurs it hide's the loader instead show it on failing response.

```
.config(function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push('mrnHttpInterceptor');
  var spinnerFunction = function (data) {
    //$('.msloader').show();
    return data;
  };
  $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest.push(spinnerFunction);
})
.factory('mrnHttpInterceptor', function ($q) {
  return function (promise) {
    return promise.then(function (response) {
      return response;
    }, function (response) {
      //When Error....   we need to hide the loader
      $('.msloader').hide();
      return $q.reject(response);
    });
  };
})
```

Comment: What about server side? How can I unserstand it and send response to this area. Because I should send some infos to client to show the other user infos

Comment: $http are ajax request only. Which wrap ajax with promise. You can use $location service in Angular to redirect the user to the other area of your web depending on the value you get for the user.

Comment: But responses are not coming to ajax global error area? If I success to drop reauest to ajax error, it also fine but it does not :(